# How to type French quotation marks on US-Intl layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

```
$ setxkbmap -query | grep layout
layout:     us
```

I believe I specified a US-Intl keyboard layout during installation of Linux Mint 18.3 (subsidiary question, how to check that?). I'm able to get accents, for example, <kbd>right-alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> prints `ç`

But not French quotation marks. I tried <kbd>right-alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>right-alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, and <kbd>right-alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, which are solutions found in several posts/Wikipedia, they don't produce `«`.

Update:

```
$ cat -n /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us | head -n 120 | tail -n 14
   107      key <AC04> { [     f,          F,             f,                F ] };
   108      key <AC05> { [     g,          G,             g,                G ] };
   109      key <AC06> { [     h,          H,             h,                H ] };
   110      key <AC07> { [     j,          J,             j,                J ] };
   111      key <AC08> { [     k,          K,            oe,               OE ] };
   112  
   113      key <AC09> { [     l,          L,        oslash,         Ooblique ] };
   114      key <AC10> { [ semicolon,      colon,     paragraph,           degree ] };
   115      key <AC11> { [dead_acute, dead_diaeresis, apostrophe,        quotedbl ] };
   116  
   117      key <AB01> { [     z,          Z,            ae,               AE ] };
   118      key <AB02> { [     x,          X,             x,                X ] };
   119      key <AB03> { [     c,          C,     copyright,             cent ] };
   120      key <AB04> { [     v,          V,             v,                V ] };

$ cat -n /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us | grep quotemark
    86      key <AE09> { [     9,  parenleft, leftsinglequotemark, dead_breve ] };
    87      key <AE10> { [     0, parenright, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
   101      key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  guillemotleft, leftdoublequotemark ] };
   102      key <AD12> { [bracketright, braceright, guillemotright, rightdoublequotemark ] };
   170    key <AE09> { [      9, parenleft, leftsinglequotemark,  dead_breve ] };
   171    key <AE10> { [      0, parenright, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
   270      key <AE09> { [     9,  parenleft, leftsinglequotemark, dead_breve ] };
   271      key <AE10> { [     0, parenright, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
   272      key <AE11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  guillemotleft, leftdoublequotemark ] };
   273      key <AE12> { [bracketright, braceright, guillemotright, rightdoublequotemark ] };
   677      key <AE10> { [     0, parenright,     masculine,singlelowquotemark] };
   682      key <AD02> { [     w,          W,         U2211,doublelowquotemark] };
   691      key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft, leftdoublequotemark, rightdoublequotemark ] };
   692      key <AD12> { [bracketright, braceright, leftsinglequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ] };
   741      key <AE09> { [            9,    parenleft,  leftsinglequotemark,  leftdoublequotemark ] };
   742      key <AE10> { [            0,   parenright, rightsinglequotemark,  rightdoublequotemark ] };
   871              leftsinglequotemark,    dead_breve  ] };
   873              rightsinglequotemark,   dead_abovering  ] };
   917              leftsinglequotemark,    dead_breve  ] };
   919              rightsinglequotemark,   dead_abovering  ] };
   950              leftsinglequotemark,    dead_breve  ] };
   952              rightsinglequotemark,   dead_abovering  ] };
  1459   key <AE09> { [  9, parenleft, leftsinglequotemark, U0306 ] };
  1461   key <AE10> { [  0, parenright, rightsinglequotemark, U030A ] };
```

Not sure what is the "standard kb".
    dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration 
[image]

Comment: <Compose><<><<> and <Compose><>><>> *runs*

Comment: Does `xmodmap -pke | grep -i guil` return anything?

Comment: @roaima, am I missing something? There's the "Compose" key mentioned at that "duplicate", but apart from that I can't see how the two questions are related.

Comment: @stéphanechazelas it seems to me they're asking the same thing - how to get characters not found on one's keyboard. I've just updated the answer there to include an example of how to get «. Maybe that was what was missing.

Comment: @roaima, using the Compose key, (on systems/input systems/applications that have one) can be one answer to both questions, but there can be other answers to both questions and both questions are very different one from the other. Knowing how to enter « in one context, does not necessarily help in knowing how to have a dead key apply to the previously pressed key.

Comment: Does xmodmap -pke | grep -i guil return anything? No. I don't see a compose key on my kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us file in the section "intl" (English (US, intl., with dead keys) has the guillemets as third option on the [ and ] key, as you correctly assumed.

Please check if your /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us file has the same entries (should be around line 114 or so), and also check if you really selected the "intl" variant of the US keyboard layout, when you run setxkbmap -query under variant it should spell "intl" and not something else.

Comment: $ setxkbmap -query shows 'variant:    alt-intl'

Comment: well, alt-intl does indeed define not define the guillemets". The "intl" (without the alt) does have the guillemets, as seen in line 110 of your amended post. So you should change the variant to the "intl" instead of "alt-intl". Don’t know really how, but directly from the command line setxkbmap us intl should do the trick

Comment: PS: how to make the change permanent: I appended `setxkbmap us intl` to `~/.profile`, it seems to be ignored.

Comment: are you sure .profile is sourced when you open a shell? You should read up on .bashrc, login shells and normal interactive shells etc. Also, .xinitrc might also be a place to put X-specific commands into.